# Change profile in aws java project

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have created a simple aws dynamodb java project in Eclipse. I have set my profile, secret key and all other information in Aws plugin of Java.

Even while creating the new aws dynamodb project also, i have chosen my profile. However after compiling and running the code, i'm getting an error saying.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'default'"
```

I know that its because of the default profile. But while creating new project itself i have chosen "my custom profile"

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change a profile, you should set `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable before you start Eclipse.

1. Edit your crednetial file and define your custom profile.

   ```
   $ vi ~/.aws/credentials
   [sample-profile]
   aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   region = ap-northeast-1
   ```
2. Edit your bash_profile to define `AWS_PROFILE`.

   ```
   $ vi ~/.bash_profile
   export AWS_PROFILE=sample-profile
   ```
3. Restart your Eclipse.

After this, I think you can access to AWS using your custom profile.

Please read the following documentation for details:
[Providing AWS Credentials in the AWS SDK for Java — Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html#using-the-default-credential-provider-chain)

Comment: `System.setProperty("aws.profile", "foo")` will use the [foo] profile in ~/.aws/credentials

Answer (score 1):

if you are on windows go to C:\Users\Your_user_name.aws

here in this location create a file called credentials

go to your aws accounts homescreen

click on *commandline or programmatic access*

a modal will pop up , chose the option 2 in it ."add a profile to your aws credentials file"

copy and paste them to your newly created credentials file

change the user name to default so that you have a profile named default

restart the IDE

this should sort your issue.

if you are using linux follow the same steps only location of your credentials file should change. in linux its home -> .aws -> credentials

Comment: For some reason, I cannot get named profiles to work in Eclipse -- if I set AWS_PROFILE, suddenly Spring doesn't work. As you did, I have to put the access key values into the default profile manually.